# Centos7.4 DNS Issue: Unable To Resolve Domains via Ping But NSLOOKUP Working

Tags: dns, centos, centos7

I have been unable to resolve domains via ping however DIG, NSLOOKUP and HOST are resolving domains just fine.

```
[root@xxx ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 114.114.114.114
nameserver 8.8.8.8
[root@xxx ~]# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts
hosts:      files dns myhostname mdns
[root@xxx ~]# ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.<br/>
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=71.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 71.173/71.173/71.173/0.000 ms
[root@xxx ~]#
[root@xxx ~]# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known

[root@xxx ~]# host google.com
        google.com has address 216.58.223.110
        google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:401a:804::200e
        google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
        google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
        google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
        google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
        google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
        [root@xxx ~]# nslookup google.com
    Server:         127.0.0.1
    Address:        127.0.0.1#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 216.58.223.110

    [root@xxx ~]# dig google.com

    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-51.el7 <<>> google.com
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64421
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;google.com.                    IN      A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    google.com.             290     IN      A       216.58.223.110

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    google.com.             172790  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
    google.com.             172790  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
    google.com.             172790  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
    google.com.             172790  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.

    ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    ns2.google.com.         172790  IN      A       216.239.34.10
    ns2.google.com.         172790  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
    ns1.google.com.         172790  IN      A       216.239.32.10
    ns1.google.com.         172790  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
    ns3.google.com.         172790  IN      A       216.239.36.10
    ns3.google.com.         172790  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
    ns4.google.com.         172790  IN      A       216.239.38.10
    ns4.google.com.         172790  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a

    ;; Query time: 1 msec
    ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
    ;; WHEN: Fri Oct 19 12:13:50 CAT 2018
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 303

[root@xxx ~]#
```

Comment: At worst do an `strace` on the failing ping to see how it is attempting to resolve the name. You should also show full content of `resolv.conf` as other options there could have an impact.

Comment: Do you use `nscd`?